# What command changes the Group setting for a directory?

Tags: permissions

I am having an access problem to some files and directories that I have tracked down to the group assigned to access them.

When I manually change the name of the group in the properties/permissions menu for a directory from the default setting (MyGroup) to www-data used by my Drupal Website, the directory error messages I get are gone.

There are a large number of files and directories that require this change.  If believe using chmod will change the owner which is set correctly and being new to Ubuntu, I am reluctant to experiment without a better understanding of how owner and groups work in the permissions settings.

What command changes the Group setting for a directory?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`chmod` does not change owner. It changes permissions. `chown` changes owner (and group if need be) and `chgrp` changes group.

You can use

```
chown {-R} [user]{:group} [file|directory]
```

to set user and group ownership where `-R` does everything that is inside `directory`.
So `sudo chown -R rinzwind:rinzwind /tmp/` would set `/tmp/` and everything in it to user rinzwind and group rinzwind.

There is also

```
chgrp {-R} [group] [file|directory]
```

if you do not need to touch the user permissions and only need to set the group.

Oh and you can check what group a user belongs to with `groups {username}`.

Comment: I get permissions issue

Answer (score 23):

In addition to Rinzwind's answer, you might also use `chown :group [file|directory]` to change the group only and leave the owner intact.

Comment: That's what Rinzwind's answer already says though not as clearly. I guess your answer is not a duplicate then.

Comment: This wasn't obvious at all from Rinzwind's answer, so this one helps, actually

Answer (score 2):

To change group to current user, use this:

```
sudo chgrp -R $USER ~/.blabla
```

Comment: For me, this was a helpful addition, specifying the $USER variable to set it to the current user. Probably widely known for many Ubuntu users, but being new to it myself, I appreciated this person's contribution.

Comment: @McHobbes thx. At least I helped one person :)